# SQL delete where column_b doesn't contain column_a

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

```
domain      | email
------------|---------------------
banana.com  | user@banana.com,user@gmail.com
pear.com    | user@yahoo.com
grape.com   | user@aol.com
```

I want to delete all rows where 'domain' isn't contained within 'email'.

So, in the example above, #2 & #3 should be deleted with only #1 remaining.

This may be simple for an experienced SQL user but as a novice, and having searched, I cannot figure out how to do this. Any lead in the right direction would be appreciated.

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

You might use [`strpos`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) string function as :

```
delete from tab where strpos(email,domain)=0;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](http://rextester.com/HFB58541)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `not like` condition:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE  email NOT LIKE '%' || domain || '%'
```

Comment: `||` in MySQL? That does not work unless you have enabled some sql_mode.(PIPES_AS_CONCAT)

Comment: @RaymondNijland - OP said "I'm using PostgreSQL"

Comment: "OP said "I'm using PostgreSQL" o didn't even noticed that.. i saw the tag MySQL and browsed the MySQl tag.

Comment: You're probably going to want to put word boundary logic into your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Storing lists of things in a string is a really bad idea in SQL.  In Postgres, you can unnest the emails and then compare to the domains:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from unnest(string_to_array(str, ','::text)) u(email)
                  where u.email like '%@' || t.domain
                 );
```

This is safer than a "raw" string comparison, just in case the domain was embedded in the email address, but not the complete domain.